# Does bounded in $L^1$ on a finite measure with convergence in distribution imply convergence in $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume $P(\Omega)=1$, that $\int_{\Omega}|X_n|^2dP \leq N$ for all $n$ and that $X_n$ converges to $Y$ in distribution with $Y \in L^1(\Omega)$ .  Vitali's convergence theorem states that if $X_n$ is uniformly integrable and if $X_n \to Y$ pointwise then they also converge in $L^1$.  I'm wondering if we can weaken the statement to just the conditions that I've given and still get $X_n$ converges to $Y$ in $L^1$ if we know already that $Y$ is $L^1$ and that the measure of the whole space is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because convergence in distribution doesn't relate in general to any other kind of convergence. An example can be as follow: let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P) $ a probability space and $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ a square integrable random variable.

Now define the infinite product space $H:=\prod_{k\geqslant 1}\Omega _k$ where each $\Omega _k=\Omega $. Then Kolmogorov's extension theorem show us that we can define a probability measure $Q$ in $H$ such that $Q= \prod_{k\geqslant 1}P_k$, that is, $Q$ is an infinite product measure.

Then you can set $X_k:=(1,1,\ldots ,1,X,1,\ldots ,1,\ldots )$ where $X$ is in the $k$-th position of the infinite vector. Then $X_k:H\to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable for each $k$ and $\{X_k\}_k$ is a sequence of i.i.d. r.v. Now finally setting $Y:=X_1$ we have that $X_k\to Y$ in distribution (as they have all the same distribution), however $X_k$ converges to $Y$ pointwise nowhere, neither in $L_1$.